# Splitting a Tensor channelwise

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am dumping a tensor of size `[1,3,224,224]` to a file and would like to split into 3 tensors of size `[1,1,224,224]`, one for each RGB channel and dump them into 3 separate files. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is by a loop:

```py
for c in range(x.shape[1]):
  torch.save(x[:, c:c+1, ...], f'channel{c}.pth')
```

Note the indexing of the second (channel) dimension: you want the saved tensor to have a singleton channel dimension. If you were to index it using `x[:, c, ...]` you will get a tensor of shape `[1, 224, 224]` (no channel dimension at all).